# Why can't template argument be resolved from std::addressof<int>?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Clang and GCC (except for MSVC) fail to resolve a template argument when it's passed `std::addressof<int>` as an argument to the template function. The following is an example of such error:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int*> pv(iv.size());
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), pv.begin(), std::addressof<int>);
```

Clang:

```
<source>:8:5: error: no matching function for call to 'transform'
    std::transform(iv.begin(), iv.end(), piv.begin(), std::addressof<int>);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-5.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2028:1: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_UnaryOperation'
transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _OutputIterator __result, _UnaryOperation __op)
^
```

GCC:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4295:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:8:74: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function 'addressof<int>'
     std::transform(iv.begin(), iv.end(), piv.begin(), std::addressof<int>);
                                                                          ^
```

That error would make sense if the argument was instead an `std::addressof`, because the `UnaryOperator` template parameter would be ambiguous. However, the compiler doesn't need to deduce what `T` is in `std::addressof<int>`, I'd except no ambiguity here.

Here's a working example of my expectations (compiles on Clang 5 and GCC 7.2):

```
template <typename T>
T* addrof(T& a)
{
    return __builtin_addressof(a);  
}

template <typename F, typename T>
void foo(F f, T& a)
{
    f(a);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    foo(addrof<int>, a);
}
```

My doubt is: why can't `std::transform`s template argument be deduced from `std::addressof<int>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't work in your example because there are two overloads for each template `std::addressof` since C++ 17 (one getting the address and a deleted version which takes an rvalue reference), and it is ambiguous for the compiler which one to choose. Easiest solution is to use lambda:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void foo() {
   std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
   std::vector<int*> pv(v.size());
   std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), pv.begin(), 
                  [](int& i) { return std::addressof(i);});
}
```

Those overloads are listed here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof

The other option is to use cast, but it is just ugly, and Thy Should Prefer Lambdas! Nevertheless, will provide for completness:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void foo() {
   std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
   std::vector<int*> pv(v.size());

   std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), pv.begin(), 
                  static_cast<int* (*)(int&) >(std::addressof<int>));
}
```

Comment: Do you know which proposal changed that?